# TYPE MISMATCH - This function cannot handle the argument sent through the (|>) pipe:

Tags: elm

I am a super elm begginer and trying to make app.
Currently I am struggling to make landing page and http request to a server.
But, I am stuck here...

I have init function something like this below.

```
init : () -> Url.Url -> Nav.Key -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags url key =
    Model key TopPage
        |> goTo (Route.parse url)
```

The definition of my Model is below.

```
-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { key : Nav.Key
    , page : Page
    , name : String
    , tags : List Tag
    , jwt : String }
```

and, goTo function is below.

```
goTo : Maybe Route -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
goTo maybeRoute model =
    case maybeRoute of
        Nothing ->
            ( { model | page = NotFound }, Cmd.none )

        Just Route.Top ->
            ( { model | page = TopPage }, Cmd.none )
...
```

type Route is below.

```
type Route
    = Top
    | User String
    | Repo String String


parse : Url -> Maybe Route
parse url =
    Url.Parser.parse parser url


parser : Parser (Route -> a) a
parser =
    oneOf
        [ map Top top
        , map User string
        , map Repo (string </> string)
        ]
```

but following error has occured.

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH -------------------------------------------------- src/Main.elm

This function cannot handle the argument sent through the (|>) pipe:

54|     Model key TopPage
55|         |> goTo (Route.parse url)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The argument is:

    String -> List Tag -> String -> Model

But (|>) is piping it a function that expects:

    Model
```

What did I make mistake here?....

Comment: Can you provide your definition of Model? I'm guessing it has five fields instead of the two to you are providing in the constructor (Model key TopPage)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question!!!
I just added the definition of Model. it has five fields as you said.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Model` type has five fields, but in the line

```
    Model key TopPage
```

you are only providing values for the first two of the five.  You are missing values for the `name`, `tags` and `jwt` fields.  Provide values for these and the problem should go away.

When you declare a type alias such as `Model`, Elm creates a constructor function also named `Model`.  Elm functions support partial application, in that if you pass in values for some but not all of the arguments, you end up with a function that takes in the rest of the values.  You provided two arguments, so you end up with a function that takes three arguments and returns a `Model`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of building a value of a type. Given a simple example of a `Person` type alias:

```elm
type alias Person = { name : String, age : Int }
```

You can construct a value by specifying all fields (note that you don't have to specify `Person` in the constructor; Elm's compiler is smart enough to know it by its shape):

```elm
jane : Person
jane = { name = "Jane", age = 35 }
```

Or you can build a value by using the type name and specify each field's values in the order in which they were defined. In this style, you can think of `Person` acting like a function with two parameters that returns a `Person` value.

```elm
jane : Person
jane = Person "Jane" 35
```

In each case, you have to specify *all* fields of the type when you construct it in order to obtain a complete `Person` value. However, that is not the complete story. It is possible to leave off the age parameter when constructing a `Person`, but the result isn't a `Person`, it's a function that takes an `age` and returns a `Person`. In other words,

```elm
janeAged : Int -> Person
janeAged = Person "Jane"
```

You can strip off as many parameters from the end as you'd like to make more variations on that constructor, even stripping out all parameters:

```elm
somebody : String -> Int -> Person
somebody = Person
```

Back to your example. You are constructing a `Model` value by only specifying two parameters (`Model key TopPage`). The value of that expression does not result in a `Model`, but in a function that takes three more parameters to create a `Model`. And that's why the error message indicated you need three parameters to construct a model.

You need to specify all values of `Model` when creating it.